# Docker Compose file for Kafka with SASL authentication and a hard-coded username and password

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I want to start a Kafka instance for local development along with a web GUI. My application uses SASL (`ScramSha512`), so I want to configure the local Kafka accordingly.

Here is my `docker-compose.yaml`:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.3.0
    container_name: zookeeper
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.3.0
    container_name: broker
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
      - 9096:9096
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      ZOOKEEPER_SASL_ENABLED: "false"
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:9096,SASL_PLAINTEXT://:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:9096,SASL_PLAINTEXT://broker:9092
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_SASL_ENABLED_MECHANISMS: SCRAM-SHA-512
      KAFKA_OPTS: -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/opt/kafka/config/server-jaas.conf
    volumes:
      - ./kafka/config/:/opt/kafka/config/

  redpanda:
    image: redpandadata/console:v2.2.0
    container_name: redpanda
    depends_on:
      - broker
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKERS: broker:9092
      KAFKA_TLS_ENABLED: "false"
      KAFKA_SASL_ENABLED: "true"
      KAFKA_SASL_USERNAME: redpanda
      KAFKA_SASL_PASSWORD: redpandasecret123
      KAFKA_SASL_MECHANISM: SCRAM-SHA-512
      KAFKA_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: SASL_PLAINTEXT
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

And `kafka/config/server-jaas.conf`:

```
KafkaServer {
  org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required
  username="admin"
  password="adminsecret123"

  user_redpanda="redpandasecret123"
  ;
}
;
```

Currently, `redpanda` fails to authenticate with "invalid credentials":

```
redpanda     | {"level":"error","ts":"2023-04-24T16:39:54.221Z","msg":"unable to initialize sasl","source":"kafka_client","broker":"seed 0","err":"Authentication failed during authentication due to invalid credentials with SASL mechanism SCRAM-SHA-512: SASL_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED: SASL Authentication failed."}
```

How can I resolve this?

---

Another attempt using Kafka UI:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.3.0
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    networks:
      - kafka

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.3.0
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
      - 9096:9096
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      ZOOKEEPER_SASL_ENABLED: "false"
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: 'PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT'
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: broker
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'PLAINTEXT://broker:9092,SASL_PLAINTEXT://broker:9096'
      KAFKA_OPTS: "-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/jaas/kafka_server.conf"
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: 'PLAINTEXT://broker:9092,SASL_PLAINTEXT://broker:9096'
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: 'PLAINTEXT'
      KAFKA_SASL_ENABLED_MECHANISMS: 'SCRAM-SHA-512'
      KAFKA_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: 'SASL_PLAINTEXT'
      KAFKA_SUPER_USERS: 'User:admin,User:redpanda'
    volumes:
      - ./kafka/config/:/etc/kafka/jaas/
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    networks:
      - kafka

  kafka-ui:
    image: provectuslabs/kafka-ui:v0.6.2
    depends_on:
      - broker
    environment:
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS: broker:9096
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_PROPERTIES_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: SASL_PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_PROPERTIES_SASL_MECHANISM: SCRAM-SHA-512
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_PROPERTIES_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG: 'org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="redpanda" password="redpandasecret123";'
      DYNAMIC_CONFIG_ENABLED: "true"
    networks:
      - kafka
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

networks:
  kafka:
    name: kafka
```

I appears to be an issue with the Broker configuration.

Comment: 1) localhost:9092 is referring to redpanda container itself, not the Kafka broker. That's probably why it's failing. Authentication doesn't change that 2) Your broker only has PLAINTEXT listeners. Why would there be authentication needed? What have you tried already to change this?

Comment: Hi, can you share your solution if you could solve the problem

Answer (score -1):

It's not simply a compose file change. You need to write JAAS files for SASL and generate TLS certificates for SSL. Then, you need to configure user accounts on Kafka using CLI commands...

[This course](https://developer.confluent.io/learn-kafka/security/authentication-ssl-and-sasl-ssl/) covers everything for doing it outside of Docker, but can be converted. For example, whenever it mentions a broker config, you put that in an environment variable in all caps with underscores such as

```
KAFKA_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM: ""
```

If not wanting TLS encryption, see [these docs](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/authentication_sasl/authentication_sasl_plain.html)

If you use bitnami Kafka containers, instead, there's variables like `KAFKA_CLIENT_USERS` that does something with access controls, I believe

> Currently, redpanda fails to connect

Your address is wrong

```
KAFKA_BROKERS: "broker:29092"
```

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer I attempted to follow those docs but have hit an auth error. Any advice?

Comment: Not sure. I've never used redpanda console. Maybe you can try and debug from kafka-console-consumer? Does it connect okay when you use port 9096 to rule out other network issues?

Comment: I have made another attempt using Kafka UI and the issue is similar. I believe that the SASL credentials are not being added to the broker.

Comment: You can `docker compose exec` into the broker and `cat` the `server.properties` file. And run `ps -ef` to see the Kafka JVM arguments